# Spring boot @Retryable not working in service class

Tags: spring-boot, spring-retry

I'm trying to add retry logic in my application for sending mail to respective users through rest controller and i have annotate `@EnableRetry` in my SpringbootApplication class file

```
@RestController
public class TserviceController {
    @Autowired
    private Tservice tService ;


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/sendMail")
    public Object sayHello(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        try{
            boolean t = tService.sendConfirmationMail();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("--> rest failed");
            return ResponseEntity.status(500).body("error");
        }

        return ResponseEntity.status(200).body("success");
    }

 }
```

My `Tservice.class`

```
@Service
public class Tservice {

    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;
    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    public Tservice(JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
        this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
    }

    @Retryable(backoff = @Backoff(delay = 5000), maxAttempts = 3)
    public boolean sendConfirmationMail() throws Exception  {
        try{
            System.out.println("--> mail service calling");
            SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
            mailMessage.setTo(toEmail);
            mailMessage.setSubject(subject);
            mailMessage.setText(message);

            mailMessage.setFrom(emailFrom);

            javaMailSender.send(mailMessage);
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new Exception(e);
        }

    }

    @Recover
    public void recover(Exception ex) {
       System.out.println("--> service failed");
    }

}
```

When i try to run the `/sendMail` and whenever exception arise in service class it retrying 3 times successfully but after reaching the maxattempts, i'm getting the console print as below

```
--> mail service calling
--> mail service calling
--> mail service calling
--> rest failed
```

instead of printing 
`--> service failed`
Here what im doing wrong..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per Javadoc for `@Recover` your recover method must have the same return type as the Retryable method.

So it should be

```
@Recover
public boolean recover(Exception ex) {
   System.out.println("--> service failed");

   return false;
}
```

JavaDoc:

> A suitable recovery handler has a first parameter of type Throwable (or a subtype of Throwable) and a return value of the same type as the `@Retryable` method to recover from.

Comment: Thanks a lot..i didnt noticed that

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer if it suits your needs.